How to write enum validator in Spring boot to be used in reactive way
Problem Stmt: I want to validate the Enum values that are sent from Json format from POSTMAN via a REST API.
I followed this URL for the Enum validation
https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validations-enums
But this is validating only when I am considering/changing the Enum Data type to String and applying the annotation on it in the Model class having the enum.
When I am changing this to Enum in model this does not work....
I tried to validate it considering as String as per the document in the url that works but considering it as Enum in the Model does not works

It's not clear what you want to do and what is the problem. Please give some code examples

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
